# corrupted iso image

Tags: 13.10, iso

How can I download a complete iso?

I have downloaded `13.10` in each variation using different browsers and even torrent.  When I burn them to dvd or create a bootable usb, they won't boot from any machine. Each download has something missing.

Answer (score 1):

Download from [Ubuntu official release directory](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/) and then check if its MD5 sum is OK (from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/MD5SUMS)), so you will know if the image is good or not.

To check the md5:

```
$ md5sum xxx.iso
```

md5sum is in the coreutils package, so if you don't already have it in the system:

```
$ sudo apt-get install coreutils
```